# Android Fabric Twitter Timeline

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I am trying to show a user timeline in an android fragment. My HomeFragment.java onCreate() looks like this:

```
public class HomeFragment extends ListFragment {

@InjectView(android.R.id.list) ListView mTimeline;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mSectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
    }

    final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder().screenName("fabric").build();
    final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter(getActivity(), userTimeline);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

And my fragment_home.xml has this listview:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

HomeFragment is a fragment of HomeActivity. This code just shows an empty list. How do I fix this problem? I would also like to know how `setListAdapter(adapter);` works. How does it know which list to set the adapter to since it can't be called on any particular list. I used this [twitter fabric](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/show-timelines) page for reference when writing this code.

Answer (score 0):

Inflate your custom layout fragment_home.xml in the `ListFragment`by overriding `onCreateView`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

Your layout contains a `ListView` with the special `@android:id/list` id which identifies the `ListView` ListFragment's setListAdapter will use.

Also, `TweetTimelineListAdapter` is just a `ListAdapter`.
If you'd like to find your own `ListView` and set the adapter yourself, use an ordinary `Fragment` (not a `ListFragment`).

```
mTimeline.setListAdapter(adapter)  // mTimeline is a ListView
```

The docs include a [ListFragment example](http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-timelines.html#listfragment).